# X axis stops working sometimes on my Tronxy X5SA

Tags: stepper-driver, stepper, x-axis, fans, tronxy-x5

This is regarding the circuit of my 3D printer Tronxy X5SA's stepper motor for X axis.

**I had an observation:** It has a cooling fan (40X10 24V) which is having issues lately - it stops working sometimes, and when pushed to rotate, spins back.

**Problem:** Now one of the stepper motors (NEMA 17 ~3.5kgfcm) in my core XY has been malfunctioning, where it misses rotation sometimes out of the blue, which shifts the whole print. I thought this is due to the driver limiting the current to the motor, so I rotated the screw terminal clockwise a bit more to allow more current for the motor. This works fine for a while, but the problem comes back.

Now, I also noticed a few times that this issue occurred when the cooling fan for the drivers stopped working.

Can the stopping of the cooling fan cause the stepper motor to falter?

Another observation is that the stepper motor which is faltering is placed close to another stepper motor. Although I know stepper motors can work in extreme conditions, can this cause the issue?

If you require any more info to investigate the issue, please do let me know

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Rising voltage helps at some degree. I mean the voltage of power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the stepper motor drivers overheat, they shut down or skip steps, that is very possibly related to the failing stepper driver cooling fans.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that was the case. I cleaned the fan thoroughly so it was running at full speed (I could say by the improvement in air flow), and now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

It might be cross-talk with back-EMF from the fan confusing the stepper-motor driver. Do the cables run together, and have you tried separating them?